# Как зашифровать классы (.java) с помощью плагина cordova-plugin-crypt-file? в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Вот источник http://helpexe.ru/programmirovanie/kak-zashifrovat-zashhitit-ishodnyj-kod

я полагаю , что автоматически шифруются все файлы CSS, HTM, HTML и JS внутри каталога www:

Как  сделать чтобы шифровались классы (.java) ?

В источнике указано  , что нужно изменить    plugin.xml расположенный в /project/plugins/cordova-plugin-crypt-file и измените тег cryptfiles.

Не могу найти plugin.xml!!  и  что конкретно в нем дописывать ?!.